# Locating the "largest file number" for each subfolder in many subfolders?

Tags: php, regex, directory

(related to my previous questiuon)

i've got 100s of fileswith names like:

```
CPC_2001_5_21_7.pdf 
CPC_YYYY_M_DD_X.pdf

CPC_2001_12_21_70.pdf 
CPC_YYYY_MM_DD_XX.pdf
```

now sorted into folders like:

```
 YYYYMMDD
```

I need to locate the "highest" XX number in each folder.

i'm using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put file list into array and iterate through it:

```
// ex. glob('*.pdf');
$files = array(
    'CPC_2001_5_21_7.pdf',
    'CPC_2001_12_21_70.pdf',
    'CPC_2001_03_06_56.pdf',
    'CPC_2001_9_12_8.pdf'
);

$max = 0;
foreach($files as $f){
    sscanf($f, '%s_%d_%d_%d_%d.pdf', $str, $year, $month, $day, $xx);

    if($xx > $max)
        $max = $xx;
}
```